# Weird string calculation

Tags: code-golf

String is given in form of a variable. Let's call that variable `s`. It is known that the string looks like a calculation expression using `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`. There's no parentheses.

**Calculate the expression inside the string** and store the result in variable `r` (you can assume it's already declared). All the divisions can be performed without remainders (`4-6*3/8` is invalid because 8 is not divisible by 3). Length of string is not limited. String can't contain `0`.

Challenge is not supposed to give advantage for some languages, so I decided to change some math rules:

Operators precedence is a little bit different than it is in math and programming language expressions: multiplication/division is still higher than addition/substraction. However, if there're some multiplications/divisions in a row, it is performed right-to-left. Addition/substraction is preformed left-to-right.

Sample `s` and `r`:

`2+5-6/9*8+7` -> `2`

`1/3*6-6` -> `12`

The shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: You know, you can also just say don't use any `eval` equivalents.

Comment: Nice point. But new math rules sound like more fun ;)

Comment: You're also not really supposed to change the question after you post it, because you could invalidate previously posted answers. In this case it doesn't matter, but to iron out any mistakes/gotchas, you can post your question in the sandbox (on meta) first to discuss it.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was thinking not much people viewed the question text at that point, so I could change it a little bit. "In runtime." Sorry.

Comment: @gthacoder Only me and marinus :) I've added on a solution that meets all the new requirements.

Comment: "(`4-6*3/8` is invalid because 8 is not divisible by 3)" makes no sense: if you said that it's invalid because 18 is not divisible by 8 then I could understand it. But your examples go on to use divisions which you've defined as invalid. What you say about operator precedence also makes no sense, because you say you've made it a little different from programming language expressions and then define it to behave in the standard way.

Comment: @PeterTaylor What he means is, if you read division and multiplication from right to left, operator order **and** the dividend/divisor are reversed, so with his rules `3/9` equals `3`.

Comment: You may want to add an example that uses negative numbers as they can be easy to overlook or mistreat as minus operators. **Example:** `-5+2/-8` should equal `-9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Perl 5, <s>27</s> 20

```
s/(.)\//1\/$1*/g;print eval
```

**Edit:**

```
s/\//**-1*/g;$r=eval
```

---

Assuming the input of:

> $_ = "2+5-6/9*8+7";
>   > $r = 2

and

> $_ = "1/3*6-6";
>   > $r = 12

This regex is based in the mathematical theory of `@ybeltukov`, I'm new to regex so it probably could be much better.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica (41)

```
s = "2+5-6/9*8+7";
ToExpression@StringReplace[s,"/"->"^-1 "]
```

> 2

Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 24

```
 r=eval s.gsub ?/,'**-1*'
```

Thank you to @ybeltukov for the Mathematica technique. I *thought* there might be a substitution that could be used to leverage `eval` and yours was much simpler than the crazy regexes I was trying!

This shortcut effectively changes the operator precedence in `s` to what the question requires. It has the side effect of sometimes resulting in a `Rational` object type (e.g. `2/1` == `2`). The results are correct for the cases I've tried.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (213 characters compacted, 133 if I'm willing to sacrifice my soul)

For clarity, this is the code *before* I compacted it down ([JS-Fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/5W3nQ/)):

```
function math(match, leftDigit, operator, rightDigit, offset, string) {
    var L = parseInt(leftDigit)
    var R = parseInt(rightDigit)
    switch (operator)
    {
        case '*': return R*L;
        case '\/': return R/L;
        case '+': return L+R;
        case '-': return L-R;
    }
};

multAndDivRegex = /(\-?\d+)([\*\/])(\-?\d+)(?=[^\*\/]*$)/; //Right to left
addAndSubRegex = /(\-?\d+)([\+\-])(\-?\d+)/; // Left to right

while(multAndDivRegex.test(str)) {
    str = str.replace(multAndDivRegex, math);
}

while(addAndSubRegex.test(str)) {
    str = str.replace(addAndSubRegex, math);
}
```

Here it is compacted down to 213 characters (containing some extra help from [**Toni Almeida**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11123/toni-almeida)) ([JS-Fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/5W3nQ/5/)):

```
function m(x,l,o,r){
    L=~~l;R=~~r;
    return o=='*'?R*L:o=='/'?R/L:o=='+'?L+R:L-R
}

for(M=/(\-?\d+)([\*\/])(\-?\d+)(?=[^\*\/]*$)/;M.test(s);s=s.replace(M,m));
for(A=/(\-?\d+)([\+\-])(\-?\d+)/;A.test(r=s);s=s.replace(A,m));
```

Since I'm ending lines with semi-colons, all *removable* whitespace was ignored for character counting, but left in for clarity.

I can get it down to 133 characters if I use `eval()`, but that's not how I roll... ([JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/5W3nQ/6/))

```
function m(x,l,o,r){return o=='*'?~~r*~~l:~~r/~~l}for(M=/(\-?\d+)([\*\/])(\-?\d+)(?=[^\*\/]*$)/;M.test(s);s=s.replace(M,m));r=eval(s)
```

This solution would mean that people can enter ANY JavaScript code they want! The 303 character version does not execute any JavaScript; it only does math.

Comment: May I say, I _loved_ this challenge! :D

Comment: Well done! Here is a compacted version of your huge switch statment: `o=='*'?R*L:o=='\/'?R/L:o=='+'?L+R:o=='-'?L-R:0`

Comment: By the way, you can save 4 characters by removing `{` and `}` from you while's, as they have only 1 instruction, they are useless.

Comment: Here is, 257 char version: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/5W3nQ/2/

Comment: @ToniAlmeida Magnificent! Thanks. I trimmed off a few more characters in addition to that after re-reading the rules about allowing the use of `s` and `r` instead of input/output functions: http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/5W3nQ/3/

Answer (score 1):

### **Python 3, 35**

```
r=int(eval(s.replace("/","**-1*")))
```

### **Python 3, 30**

If you are not scared of floating point value, try this one.

```
r=eval(s.replace("/","**-1*"))
```

Both of them evaluate the string `s` and store the result in variable `r`

Comment: This doesn't work.  It gives 0 for "4/2"

Answer (score 0):

### [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/gtb), 6

```
x?_)→R
```

6 chars and 6 bytes

**EDIT** - now that the original question has changed, here's some bloated code:

```
@iS_,"*")\\iS_,"/$_4;I,1,l?A;)-1:s;A;,2I,1)+A;&s;A;,1I→_&x?_)→R
```

I think I did a pretty good job; I made it only 63 characters ;) more than 1,000% bloat

Comment: I changed question a little bit. Now it is as supposed.

Comment: I changed answer a little bit. Now it is as required.